# Is there a tool for heading detection?

Tags: pdf, table-of-contents

Given a PDF without a TOC or bookmarks, is there a way to create a TOC by automatically detecting the headings?

Comment: PDF dont have any semantic information. Headeings can be represented differently if different pdfs so no general reliable way. A pdf is there to be printed

Comment: yes, that's why I'm looking for such a tool for that